# Running C++ in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

So I have my simple hello world program in C++ in Eclipse Juno and every time I try to run it, it says "Lunach failed. Binary not found" I installed Mingw as my compiler and stuff so I'm good there but I dont get why it wont run. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try to run your executable in a terminal, by typing its complete path?

Comment: Have you compiled the program before running? Such error comes when your compilation/linking fails.

Comment: Build First (hammer icon or cntrl + b). Then run.

Comment: You might want to share all the steps you followed before clicking `Run` on Eclipse IDE. Is it your first program on Eclipse CDT?